# How to set a Splash-screen for Next.js "mobile-only" WebApp?

Tags: reactjs, spring, animation, next.js, splash-screen

My Next.js "mobile-only" App is almost done, only one thing remaining...
A splash-screen!

And I have absolutely 0 idea where should I start to implement that

This is my app folder organisation:
[image]

This is what I had in mind:

- Rename the actual index.js in "home.js"
- Create a new page index.js
- Create an animation in it (w/ react-spring)
- at the end of the animation, set router.push to home.js

But:

- My all animation should be in absolute position to hover my layout in _app.js
- "/" will only be used for the splash-screen

I need some help to set the best files configuration for this feature.
Any thoughts?

Thanks for your help!